# PHP Script Optimization

Tags: php, optimization

I have this PHP script that sends a lot of requests to websites using cURL, and I've tried to clean it up as much as possible, but I've hit a wall. What else can I do to this script to make it faster?

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
    function remoteStatusCode($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($httpcode == 404){
            echo $url;
        }
    }
    $lines = file('wordsEn.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($lines as $n){
        remoteStatusCode('<br>https://twitter.com/'.$n);
    }
?>
```

Any suggestions are good suggestions in my book, I need all the help I can get.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fred -ii-: I'm sure it's fits SO nice

Comment: @zerkms That's what it's there for. After all, they built it; others can use it.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: this question isn't about reviewing it, but about a particular programming advice.

Comment: @zerkms Ah so, people can ask for help "and" advice on SO, correct? Personally, I'm weary of asking any kind of help and that's why I try to figure things out by myself, which 99% of the time works out in my favor. SO and Google are my two most used resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is benchmark for cUrl and Multi cUrl to get header information :

```
<?php
include_once "CURL.php";
$curl = new CURL();

$start_time = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://twitter.com" );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
}
    $end_time = microtime(true);
    echo "cUrl Timing : ";
    echo $end_time - $start_time;
    echo "\n";

$start_time = microtime(true);
$get = array(CURLOPT_HEADER=>true,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true);
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $curl->addSession("https://twitter.com",$get);
}
$datas = $curl->exec();
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "Multi cUrl Timing : ";
echo $end_time - $start_time;
echo "\n";

print_r($datas[1]);// http codes of each request


?>
```

CURL.php (referance is [here](http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading), but i made some changes to get the header information in the multi cUrl class which is CURL)

```
<?php

/**
* OO cURL Class
* Object oriented wrapper for the cURL library.
* @author David Hopkins (semlabs.co.uk)
* @version 0.3
*/
class CURL
{

    public $sessions                =   array();
    public $retry                   =   0;

    /**
    * Adds a cURL session to stack
    * @param $url string, session's URL
    * @param $opts array, optional array of cURL options and values
    */
    public function addSession( $url, $opts = false )
    {
        $this->sessions[] = curl_init( $url );
        if( $opts != false )
        {
            $key = count( $this->sessions ) - 1;
            $this->setOpts( $opts, $key );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Sets an option to a cURL session
    * @param $option constant, cURL option
    * @param $value mixed, value of option
    * @param $key int, session key to set option for
    */
    public function setOpt( $option, $value, $key = 0 )
    {
        curl_setopt( $this->sessions[$key], $option, $value );
    }

    /**
    * Sets an array of options to a cURL session
    * @param $options array, array of cURL options and values
    * @param $key int, session key to set option for
    */
    public function setOpts( $options, $key = 0 )
    {
        curl_setopt_array( $this->sessions[$key], $options );
    }

    /**
    * Executes as cURL session
    * @param $key int, optional argument if you only want to execute one session
    */
    public function exec( $key = false )
    {
        $no = count( $this->sessions );

        if( $no == 1 )
            $res = $this->execSingle();
        elseif( $no > 1 ) {
            if( $key === false )
                $res = $this->execMulti();  
            else
                $res = $this->execSingle( $key );
        }

        if( $res )
            return $res;
    }

    /**
    * Executes a single cURL session
    * @param $key int, id of session to execute
    * @return array of content if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set
    */
    public function execSingle( $key = 0 )
    {
        if( $this->retry > 0 )
        {
            $retry = $this->retry;
            $code = 0;
            while( $retry >= 0 && ( $code[0] == 0 || $code[0] >= 400 ) )
            {
                $res = curl_exec( $this->sessions[$key] );
                $code = $this->info( $key, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

                $retry--;
            }
        }
        else
            $res = curl_exec( $this->sessions[$key] );

        return $res;
    }

    /**
    * Executes a stack of sessions
    * @return array of content if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set
    */
    public function execMulti()
    {
        $mh = curl_multi_init();

        #Add all sessions to multi handle
        foreach ( $this->sessions as $i => $url )
            curl_multi_add_handle( $mh, $this->sessions[$i] );

        do
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $mh, $active );
        while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );

        while ( $active && $mrc == CURLM_OK )
        {
            if ( curl_multi_select( $mh ) != -1 )
            {
                do
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec( $mh, $active );
                while ( $mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM );
            }
        }

        if ( $mrc != CURLM_OK )
            echo "Curl multi read error $mrc\n";

        #Get content foreach session, retry if applied
        foreach ( $this->sessions as $i => $url )
        {
            $code = $this->info( $i, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
            $codes[] = $code;
            if( $code[0] > 0 && $code[0] < 400 )
                $res[] = curl_multi_getcontent( $this->sessions[$i] );
            else
            {
                if( $this->retry > 0 )
                {
                    $retry = $this->retry;
                    $this->retry -= 1;
                    $eRes = $this->execSingle( $i );

                    if( $eRes )
                        $res[] = $eRes;
                    else
                        $res[] = false;

                    $this->retry = $retry;
                    echo '1';
                }
                else
                    $res[] = false;
            }
            curl_multi_remove_handle( $mh, $this->sessions[$i] );
        }

        curl_multi_close( $mh );
        $all[] = $res;
        $all[] = $codes;
        return $all;
    }

    /**
    * Closes cURL sessions
    * @param $key int, optional session to close
    */
    public function close( $key = false )
    {
        if( $key === false )
        {
            foreach( $this->sessions as $session )
                curl_close( $session );
        }
        else
            curl_close( $this->sessions[$key] );
    }

    /**
    * Remove all cURL sessions
    */
    public function clear()
    {
        foreach( $this->sessions as $session )
            curl_close( $session );
        unset( $this->sessions );
    }

    /**
    * Returns an array of session information
    * @param $key int, optional session key to return info on
    * @param $opt constant, optional option to return
    */
    public function info( $key = false, $opt = false )
    {
        if( $key === false )
        {
            foreach( $this->sessions as $key => $session )
            {
                if( $opt )
                    $info[] = curl_getinfo( $this->sessions[$key], $opt );
                else
                    $info[] = curl_getinfo( $this->sessions[$key] );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( $opt )
                $info[] = curl_getinfo( $this->sessions[$key], $opt );
            else
                $info[] = curl_getinfo( $this->sessions[$key] );
        }

        return $info;
    }

    /**
    * Returns an array of errors
    * @param $key int, optional session key to retun error on
    * @return array of error messages
    */
    public function error( $key = false )
    {
        if( $key === false )
        {
            foreach( $this->sessions as $session )
                $errors[] = curl_error( $session );
        }
        else
            $errors[] = curl_error( $this->sessions[$key] );

        return $errors;
    }

    /**
    * Returns an array of session error numbers
    * @param $key int, optional session key to retun error on
    * @return array of error codes
    */
    public function errorNo( $key = false )
    {
        if( $key === false )
        {
            foreach( $this->sessions as $session )
                $errors[] = curl_errno( $session );
        }
        else
            $errors[] = curl_errno( $this->sessions[$key] );

        return $errors;
    }

}

?>
```

The result is :

cUrl Timing : 3.5252928733826

Multi cUrl Timing : 0.63891220092773

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

)
```

If i can help you, i'll feel very happy .

Comment: Now it's much better, +1. Are you keen to drop the other answer?

Comment: i delete my other answer to not mislead the users